# How can I ensure explicit constructors are called and allow brace initialization?

Tags: c++, explicit, list-initialization

Consider basic program below. It has `typedef int Number`, with the intent of allowing future developers to change this to whatever precision makes the most sense at the time (or even, say, use one of CGAL's number types).

You can see that a `Point` is described as a pair of `Number`, and that a `LineSegment` is described by two `Point`.

There are two goals I would like to accomplish:

1. If a User tries to instantiate a `Point` with anything other than explicitly a `Number`, it should trigger a compile-time warning. I thought that's what the `explicit` keyword does. Instead, as you can see in the instantiation of `p3`, we silently allow a `float` to be converted to an `int`
2. If a User wants to brace-initialize a `LineSegment` with constant values, it should be possible as long as these values are `Number`.

My questions:

1. Am I misunderstanding how `explicit` is supposed to be used?
2. Is it unfeasible to expect the compiler to catch this? In other words, does it need to be in the programming logic at runtime?

```cpp
typedef int Number;

class Point
{
    public:
        explicit Point(Number n1, Number n2)
            : x(n1), y(n2)
        {}

        Number x;
        Number y;
};

class LineSegment
{
    public:
        LineSegment(Point p1, Point p2)
            : start(p1), end(p2)
        {}

        Point start;
        Point end;
};

int main()
{
    // Works as expected
    Point p1(10, 10);
    Point p2(20, 20);
    LineSegment s1(p1, p2);

    // How can I trigger a compiler error here?
    Point p3(10.5, 11.5);

    // Why can't a do the following?
    //LineSegment s2({30, 30}, {40, 40});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated note: In new/modern code, I'd personally avoid any use of `typedef`. `using` can do all that `typedef` can do (and more), so it effectively supercedes it (and it's also (to me, at least) more readable). Thus, I would have made `typedef int Number;` be `using Number = int;`.

Comment: Well noted, I've actually been wondering about this. I never really took the time to read up on `using` and after having it fail at compile-time a few times (due to syntax errors on my part) I gave up 

Comment: `Point p{10.5, 11.5}` triggers your desired error message. But not because of `explicit` but because `{..}` is more picky about losing precision.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb can you point me to any resources where I can read more about this `MyClass instance{...}` syntax? This is my first time seeing it.

Comment: As for the last line, you have told the compiler that two numbers are not equivalent "in concept" than a single `Point` (that's a major use-case of `explicit` and why it disables implicit conversions). I guess your reason for this is that two numbers could just aswell mean "width and height" and many other things, so the `explicit` would seem to be justified to me. But then, the compiler will forbid you to pass two numbers where it expects a single Point.

Comment: `I guess your reason for this is that two numbers could just aswell mean "width and height" and many other things `

Actually, I wanted to use `explicit` because I wish to prevent dreaded "floating point rounding" issues. In other words, I wish for the underlying algorithms to have a guaranteed number type (easy enough) and for Users to understand that a very particular number type is being used in the calculations (that's where I'm struggling)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are misunderstanding `explicit`. `explicit` on a constructor prevents the constructor to be used e.g. as implicit user-defined conversion when something is passed to a function expecting your class type as parameter. The use of `explicit` on your constructor is actually what is preventing `LineSegment s2({30, 30}, {40, 40});` to compile for this exact reason, as @JohannesSchaub pointed out in the question comments.

`explicit` does not prevent implicit conversions in the constructor's own arguments.

You cannot avoid the implicit conversion when using the parenthesized initializer syntax, but you can obtain the actual type passed by making the constructor a template function and check its template parameter types:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
Point(T1 n1, T2 n2)
        : x(n1), y(n2)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T1,Number> && std::is_same_v<T2,Number>
        , "Construct Point with Number arguments!");
}
```

Requires `#include<type_traits>` for `std::is_same_v` and C++17. (Before C++17 you need to use `std::is_same<...>::value`.)

Alternatively you can use `std::enable_if` instead of `static_assert`, if you don't want the use with a wrong type to cause a hard error.

Comment: in your example, is it necessary to have two template parameters? The expectation is that a given `Point` will be represented by two variables of uniform `type`

Comment: @wesanyer I suppose it isn't really necessary, but the error message in the `static_assert` will not be printed if you try to call it with two different types. Instead you will get a "no matching overload" error (the same as if you were using `std::enable_if`).